# __weak general variables declaration for blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am currently working on an implementation where many blocks are used. Every block needs to communicate with self.

Currently I am doing this:

```
@implementation Foo
- (void) bar
{
    __weak Foo *weakSelf = self;
    [self doBlockStuff:^(id something) {
        [weakSelf doSomething];
    }];
}
@end
```

I have many functions that do the same with the weak instantiation.

Is it right to instantiate the weak property once in the interface block and use it everywhere?

It's working but is it an accepted practice?

```
@interface Foo ()
{
    __weak Foo *_weakSelf;  
}
@end

@implementation Foo
-(instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _weakSelf = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) bar1
{
    [self doBlockStuff:^(id something) {
        [_weakSelf doSomething];
    }];
}
- (void) bar2
{
    [self doBlockStuff:^(id something) {
        [_weakSelf doSomething];
    }];
}
- (void) bar3
{
    [self doBlockStuff:^(id something) {
        [_weakSelf doSomething];
    }];
}
- (void) bar4
{
    [self doBlockStuff:^(id something) {
        [_weakSelf doSomething];
    }];
}
@end
```

**Edit after Testing with new Informations:**
I did wrote a little test case and now i can demonstrate why the second one is not working.
In my Testclass a imake a dispatch after 5 seconds with the relevant self usage and i logged when my dealloc was called.

```
@implementation Foo

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }

    return;
}

- (void)bar
{

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self doSomething];
    });
}

@end
```

If the class loses the holder, because the controller is closed or whatever and the function is still running, the class will dialoged after the dispatch is done.

```
@interface Foo ()
{
    __weak Foo *_weakSelf;  
}
@end

@implementation Foo

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _weakSelf = self;
    }

    return;
}

- (void)bar
{

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_weakSelf doSomething];
    });
}

@end
```

This one will also on dealloc if the dispatch is done. Because the _weakSelf property is still holing by the class, a shorthand for using self->_weak. Self means self :)

```
@implementation Foo

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }

    return;
}

- (void)bar
{
     __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf doSomething];
    });
}

@end
```

this one will dealloc immediately because the weak reference is only existing in this function given to the block. The function is over and if the class loses his reference the block has no property that is holing anyone. But the weak property is still usable when the reference class is available. 
To be sure, that this weak property will be alive, we can set a strong cycle in the block.

Comment: I think is all right. However, do you get any error or crash?

Comment: no nothing, this is working in both ways. But i dont know if this could have leaks. Is the weakSelf property the same reference than self? So if i change later a property in self, this will also affected in the weakSelf one in the interface?

Comment: It won't bring leak here. __weak variable does not retain the self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't at all do what you think it does. That `__weak` instance variable in those methods? That's just a shorthand for `self->_weak`. All of those methods using the proposed manner still capture `self` strongly.

Stick to what you were doing before.

Comment: Really, though, I would suggest reading through [Apple's documentation for ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) again. Capturing `self` strongly is not itself a bad thing—in fact, it's often very useful. Learn when the use `__weak` references is actually warranted.

Comment: i thougt so also, that the second solution is also capturing strong. I didnt know how strongly it is in this kind of declaration, but when i think about a propert with weak, i would also call self.weakSelf ... haha funny. Thx fot the answer, i wiill take a look at the documentation.

Comment: If the code doesn't give a severe compiler warning (exactly for the reason that you give, because it is a hidden reference to self), then the OP urgently needs to turn on some warnings in Xcode.

Comment: if u use self in a block, than Xcode also don't shows a warning. Maybe i miss the point for what using weak is really for.
In my opinion, its for making sure, that the block has no strong reference to the main class, that means my main class can be dealloced and the block, that is maybe still active, will not block this deallocation because it has no strong reference to the class.
Setting the instance variable to weak will also let the class completely dealloc, while a block is running with this property in use.
Or jam wrong with that?

Answer (score -1):

This is really bad then if the __weakSelf still holds a strong reference. The question is that if instantiated in the method and used in the method does it still really have a weak anchor to self or is it holding a strong reference in that very moment. Based on the documentation you can instantiate a weak reference outside the block and even make it strong inside the block if you want. Take a look here

http://aceontech.com/objc/ios/2014/01/10/weakify-a-more-elegant-solution-to-weakself.html

my question at this point in time is that why does a weak self instantiated dealloc it's self when the real self deallocs..? Because I tried to hold the weak self in another viewController and then dealloc the real self. But the weak self was dealloc as soon as I dealloc the real self.